# Determine status of laptop lid

Tags: power-management, laptop

I have a weird problem where my laptop will wake when it's closed, generating a lot of heat and causing much frustration.

Is there a way that I can tell if the laptop's lid is closed so that I can automatically suspend the computer (via a cron script) if it wakes itself while the lid is closed?

Closing the lid *does* currently suspend the machine and opening it does wake it, so that works properly. It's a 2011 MacBook Pro running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with a Dell laptop running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For my specific case, I can get the status of the lid with

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state
state:    open
```

I can then just grep for `open` or `closed` to see if it's open or closed.

Comment: To note: this works on my MacBook Pro, a Dell laptop, and a Gateway laptop also, so I'm assuming this is fairly ubiquitous.

Comment: How about 2 in 1 notebooks that can have lid 360° opened? is there an indication or should we use some combination of lid open and accelerometer readings?

Comment: Answering to my own comment, I put hands on 2 in 1 (Dell) and it only reports "open/close". However, when computer goes tablet or tent mode there is a keystroke reported to disable keyboard, hence, a combination of accel, keystroke and lid "open/close" can tell if the computer is in tablet/tent mode.

Comment: This work on Linux too, however, with a slight modification: `LID` instead of `LID0` → `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state`.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer to your linux-specific question, so maybe this answer should be moved to the comments:

MacBooks of all generations are known to have some issues with their system management controller of which one of the symptoms is strange behavior on lid-close and lid-open. This support page from Apple might help you resolve the problem: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964

Comment: BSD-style systems usually have a `sysctl` value that indicates whether the lid is open or closed. `sysctl | grep lid` would yield the name of the sysctl you want. However, I don't know about the way Linux handles this.